# Disable log messages in Java zookeeper api

Tags: java, apache-zookeeper

I am getting these log messages repeatedly..

```
12:31:39.085 [localhost-startStop-1-SendThread(localhost:2182)] DEBUG org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn - Got ping response for sessionid: 0x14f7213a94000bc after 0ms

12:31:39.142 [localhost-startStop-1-SendThread(localhost:2182)] DEBUG org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn - Got ping response for sessionid: 0x14f7213a94000be after 0ms

12:31:39.142 [localhost-startStop-1-SendThread(localhost:2182)] DEBUG org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn - Got ping response for sessionid: 0x14f7213a94000bd after 0ms

12:31:39.183 [localhost-startStop-1-SendThread(localhost:2182)] DEBUG org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn - Got ping response for sessionid: 0x14f7213a94000bf after 0ms

12:31:39.183 [localhost-startStop-1-SendThread(localhost:2182)] DEBUG org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn - Got ping response for sessionid: 0x14f7213a94000c0 after 0ms

12:31:39.256 [localhost-startStop-1-SendThread(localhost:2182)] DEBUG org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn - Got ping response for sessionid: 0x14f7213a94000c1 after 0ms
```

I changed my log4j2.xml with root level = "OFF" as well.

How do I turn this logging off ?

Answer (score 1):

You could add another logger in your `log4j2.xml` to change the log level for zookeeper. Assuming you have already defined Appender named `file`, you can add the `Logger` section as shown below

```
<Appenders>
  <RollingFile name="file" ...
   ...
  </RollingFile>
</Appenders>
<Loggers>
  ...
  <Logger name="org.apache.zookeeper" level="warn" additivity="false">
    <AppenderRef ref="file"/>
  </Logger>
  ...
</Loggers>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your log level is DEBUG, that indeed is quite verbose and not meant to be used in production systems. I would increase the log level to WARN or even ERROR in the log4j.properties file (conf director). See here for a more complete explanation:

[Why does zookeeper not use my log4j.properties file log directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26612908/why-does-zookeeper-not-use-my-log4j-properties-file-log-directory)