# Zookeeper dataLogDir config invalid

Tags: apache-zookeeper

I built a zookeeper cluster and it runs very well. But I found that the log directory I set in the zoo.cfg seems not working. Below is my config about log directory and snapshots directory.

```
dataDir=/var/lib/zookeeper
dataLogDir=/var/lib/zookeeper/logs
```

However, file zookeeper.out is generated in `/var/lib/zookeeper` rather than the subsidiary log folder `/var/lib/zookeeper/logs`.

I restarted zookeeper on every server many times, but made no sense.

Comment: dataDir and dataLogDir are not in the same line, the are in 2 separated lines.

Comment: GssFlyaway, that's only stackoverflow bad formatting; put 2 spaces at line end in order to have line break

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26612908/why-does-zookeeper-not-use-my-log4j-properties-file-log-directory bin/zkServer.sh and conf/log4j.properties explained there:

    ZOO_LOG_DIR  - to set the path for both zookeeper.out and log4j.
    ZOO_LOG4J_PROP - to set the log4j logging level and what log appenders are turned on

Answer (score 2):

This happens because *zookeeper.out* is related to other type of log (*application log*) instead of the one specified by [dataLogDir](https://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/current/zookeeperAdmin.html#sc_advancedConfiguration) which relates to *transaction log*.

> **dataLogDir**
>   This option will direct the machine to write the *transaction log* to
>   the dataLogDir rather than the dataDir. This allows a dedicated log
>   device to be used, and helps avoid competition between logging and
>   snaphots.

By checking [zkServer.sh](https://github.com/apache/zookeeper/blob/master/bin/zkServer.sh) you'll see that *zookeeper.out* is related to _ZOO_DAEMON_OUT which depends on ZOO_LOG_DIR which is set by default by [zkEnv.sh](https://github.com/apache/zookeeper/blob/master/bin/zkEnv.sh). Depending on your environment and zookeeper (ZK) version the *zookeeper.out* file might land in different places (according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26612908/why-does-zookeeper-not-use-my-log4j-properties-file-log-directory?answertab=active#tab-top) even in the working directory from which ZK is started).
For *application logging* you'll better configure the [log4j.properties](https://github.com/apache/zookeeper/blob/master/conf/log4j.properties) file; that's because ZK uses [log4j](https://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/current/zookeeperAdmin.html#sc_logging).